# TCPDF error with Drupal-6 print module

Tags: image, drupal-6, tcpdf, print-module

I am using [print module](http://drupal.org/project/print) for generating pdf on my websites. Most of the part seems to work fine except when i try to use an image in my node.tpl.php file.

Even though the node page seems to show the image the print pdf page gives an error.

And this only happens when there is an image in node.tpl file.

TCPDF ERROR : Can't open image file : /.../print/tcpdf/cache/...[image]

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give permission to write the cache folder in your lib(for me: sites/all/modules/print/lib/cache) directory! for example 777

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue .permission did nt worked .Updated tcpdf version to newer one in my case tcpdf_5_9_149 to tcpdf_5_9_150 and stared working properly.The newer version has the fix for cache issues